# Why DB2 SQLFetch returns SQL_NULL_DATA only of 32 bit size even with 64 bit libraries

Tags: c++, db2, odbc, db2-luw

I have built my windows application with DB2 9.7 (tried DB2 10.5 also) 64 bit libraries. Ex: `db2cli64.lib`.

I'm using `SQLBindCol` and `SQLFetch` sequence to retrieve data from the database.

```
SQLBindCol(hStmt,
           index,
           deftyp,
           data,
           deflen,
           &len_ind_ptr)

................

SQLFetch()

.................

if(len_ind_ptr == SQL_NULL_DATA)
```

The above condition always fails in case of the data retrieved is NULL.
The type of `len_ind_ptr` is `SQLLEN` and while debugging I could see `SQLLEN` becomes `__int64` at runtime.

The value returned to this variable from `SQLFetch` is of 32 bits (in my 64 bit environment, it holds a value of 4294967295 which is not equal to -1).

In the documentations I found that the pointer `len_ind_ptr` will be assigned to two descriptors `SQL_DESC_INDICATOR_PTR` and `SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH_PTR`, when I use `SQLBindCol`.

If data is NULL, the macro `SQL_NULL_DAT`A will be assigned to `SQL_DESC_INDICATOR_PTR`. Is it possible that, this assignment stores the value only in first 32 bits? or library linking is not correct or is it really a DB2 64 bit library bug with Windows?

Note: This behaviour is not observed with ODBC drivers used for MS SQL Server.

Comment: Please give us a minimal compilable sample showing the problem. I can only say: We are working with DB2 (Express Edition and the better one running on IBMs iSeries), and SQL_NULL_DATA works on 32 and 64bit versions, using odbc.

Comment: Sorry, my application is quite huge and i haven't write any separate sample to test this. I'm having a different application which links with ODBC libraries, and follows the same sequence as above to retrieve data from MSSQL. I do not get this problem there.